# Session from GetPageItemProcessor is null in Service layer

Tags: sitecore-api, session-state, sitecore-mvc

I am having a `PageUnavailableProcessor`, which extends `GetPageItemProcessor`. This Processor helps in redirecting to a user-defined Page for all `403` errors (we are tagging the pages by language and location). So far so good. Now, we need the redirect to the actual page when the user changes/ corrects the tagging.

So we thought of adding a session variable and store the Original ItemId when the user selects wrong tagging and need to retrieve the same from session variable when the user selects/corrects tagging. The below is the code.

```
public class PageUnavailableProcessor : GetPageItemProcessor
{
    public readonly BaseClient _baseClient;

    public PageUnavailableProcessor(BaseClient baseClient) : base(baseClient)
    {
        _baseClient = baseClient;
    }

    public override void Process(GetPageItemArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current?.Request;
        
        var path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
                    
        var originalRequest = Context.Database.GetItem(path);
        if (originalRequest != null)
        {
            var originalRequestGuid = originalRequest.ID;
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("OriginalItemId", originalRequestGuid);
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure that the session variable is storing correctly (in above) but always returning null when trying to retrieve the session variable in service layer.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["OriginalItemId"] != null)
        {......}
```

when browsed for similar issues, many asked to check the sequence of processors and I can confirm that they look good as shown below.

```
<mvc.getPageItem patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config">
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.SetLanguage, Sitecore.Mvc" resolve="true"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromAlias, Sitecore.Mvc" resolve="true"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromRouteValue, Sitecore.Mvc" resolve="true"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.GetPageItem.GetErrorPageContextItem, Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromRouteUrl, Sitecore.Mvc" resolve="true"/>
**<processor type="MyNamespace.Web.Pipelines.PageUnavailableProcessor, MyNamespace.Web" resolve="true" patch:source="Pipeline.PageUnavailable.config"/>**
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageItem.GetFromOldContext, Sitecore.Mvc" resolve="true"/>
</mvc.getPageItem>
```

Any ideas or thoughts why the session is null/empty?

Comment: You REALLY should not be trying to bring in Session State for something like this. Do a read up on request blocking and session state. Drop the originalRequestGuid into a cookie instead.

Comment: @MarkCassidy Thank you. I will try with cookies shortly.